# How to add padding to drop down list that we get by clicking on spinner?

Tags: android

I have a Spinner and I have added items to it by specifying it in the xml. Now I want to mention the padding for the list view that is obtained when we click on the spinner (Note, I want padding for the entire list of item and not each item). Below is the code I use currently:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/an_id"
    android_layout_width="match_parent"
    android_layout_height="48dp">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@id/my_id"
        android:entries="@array/my_values" />

</FrameLayout>

arrays.xml:
    <string-array name="my_values">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
```

Also, I don't want to do this in the java code, I want to do it using xml file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible. define a popUpTheme as below.

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:textSize="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
             />
```

And add this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
</style>
```

and yes it works. cheers.

Comment: Some reason I don't see the change in UI at all. I updated my code, added more info. Can you suggest me why it is happening so? Also, I tried adding this inside the style I used in Spinner

Comment: I just put everything I did in xml, updated the question, and I am wondering why app:popupTheme shows error for me.

Comment: Try using this support library. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

Comment: Attention for those who do not work, perhaps you accidentally specified android:popupTheme = "@ style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" instead of app:popupTheme = "@ style / AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

Comment: @MidhunVijayakumar this worked for me. Thanks so much for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Overriding style does not work properly it has added scrollbar for me and items were being cut off. The following solution works perfectly.

Create a drawable `bg_spinner.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:top="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="yourPopupColor" />
</shape>
```

Then set `android:popupBackground="@drawable/bg_spinner_popup"` property for your `Spinner` in XML.

This works like a charm without anything being cut off etc.

Comment: Add to padding: android:left="5dp". This way text is not ugly positioned on the beggining ogf pop up

Answer (score 0):

Popup theme wasn't doing what I wanted since it seems to apply the padding to everything.
If you set a custom adapter on your spinner, which you are probably doing anyway, you can easily get a reference to correct parent view:

The method is:

`View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)`

And I use parent.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom) to set the correct padding.

Answer (score -8):

Add to your FrameLayout

```
<Spinner
 android:id="@+id/spinner"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
 android:textSize="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:dropDownWidth="200dp"/>
```

And in your theme

```
    <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
```

Comment: That's literally verbatim the answer above ^

Comment: Why would I post something that is look like it is copied from his answer? It was over a year ago, I think his answer came few hours after I post my solution. Never mind...