# Spinner dropdown outer border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

How do you set border for entire dropdown and not for items itself?

**Expectation**:

Perhaps its not clearly seen but I'm interested in that white border outside entire dropdown. See red note

[image]

**Reality**:

[image]

spinner_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_blue_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_spinner_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        style="@style/sp_squared_style"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_underline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_underline"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The layout is exactly as you want. You have an image view which is your white line. If you want less vertical margin just reduce it...

Comment: I have edited screenshot to clarify expectations. Please look at the border marked red

Comment: You should look at popup theme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222207/how-to-add-padding-to-drop-down-list-that-we-get-by-clicking-on-spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround for this. Not sure, perhaps there's better solution. Anyway:

1) `spinner_item.xml` - wrap content in a layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_stroke" //add white border
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" //set margin left and right
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp" //add bottom and top margins dynamically in adapter
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/primary_blue_dark">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_spinner_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        style="@style/sp_squared_style"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_underline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_underline"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) Add margins bottom for first element and for bottom one in Adapter:

```
public class AmountAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private TextView tvRow;
private TextView tvItem;
private LinearLayout llWrapper;
private Context context;
private ImageView ivUnderline;
private String[] values;

private int border;


public AmountAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                         String[] values) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    border = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rounding_radius_dp_1);
}

public int getCount() {
    return values.length;
}

public String getItem(int position) {
    return values[position];
}

public String[] getItems() {
    return values;
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row;

    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_spinner_row, parent, false);
    tvRow = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_spinner_row);
    return row;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;

    row = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_spinner_dropdown, null);
    llWrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.ll_wrapper);
    tvItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_spinner_item);
    tvItem.setText(values[position]);

    ivUnderline = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_underline);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );


    if (position == values.length - 1){
        ivUnderline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        int padding = (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_small);
        int paddingTop = (int)context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rounding_radius_dp);
        tvItem.setPadding(padding, paddingTop, 0, padding);

        params.setMargins(border, 0, border, border); //end part
        llWrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else if(position == 0){
        params.setMargins(border, border, border, 0); //start part
        llWrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else {
        params.setMargins(border, 0, border, 0); //middle part
        llWrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    return row;
}
}
```

3) Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the **Ben-J** comment and the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222207/how-to-add-padding-to-drop-down-list-that-we-get-by-clicking-on-spinner answer I used this code to create border using `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light` sub-style.

This will create padding for the outer list overlay wchich will show the underlying overlay background. Also you need to set an explicit background for the list items so they don't be transparent.

**layout/main_layout.xml:**

```
<Spinner xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  app:popupTheme="@style/LangList_SpinnerPopupOverlay" />
```

**values/styles.xml:**

```
<style name="LangList_SpinnerPopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
  <!-- border width -->
  <item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
  <!-- border color -->
  <item name="android:background">#f00</item>
</style>
```

**layout/spinner_list_item.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemText"
    android:background="#fff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/spinner_view.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomListAdapter.java:**

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomListItem> {

  private Context context;

  public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<CustomListItem> items) {
    super(context, R.layout.spinner_list_item, items);
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // spinner layout (when closed)
    int layoutId = R.layout.spinner_view;
    return createView(position, convertView, parent, layoutId);
  }

  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // dropdown list layout
    int layoutId = R.layout.spinner_list_item;
    return createView(position, convertView, parent, layoutId);
  }

  private View createView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int layoutId) {
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null);
    }

    TextView itemText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);

    CustomListItem item = getItem(position);
    if (item != null) {
      itemText.setText(item.getText());
    }

    return convertView;
  }

}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd11A.png]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate XML file inside drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white_overlay_8x" />
    <corners android:radius="6dip" />
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:width="@dimen/dot" />

</shape>
```

and set

```
android:background=@drawable/file;
```

in your spinner_item.xml:

Answer (score 1):

Since this one consumed much time for me to find, hopefully it will help someone...

First create a new **spinner_dropdown_border.xml** with the desired border in drawable folder:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <solid android:color="@color/basic_color"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color= "@color/border_color"/>
    </shape>
```

Then apply this border to your spinner like this:

```
   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        ...
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_dropdown_border" />
```

This will do the job only for the border and not for each item of the drop down separately:

```
android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_dropdown_border"
```

[Spinner border image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4VBL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create one **border.xml** file under **Drawable** Folder, and write the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/edittext_line_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/app_screen_back_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

After that set background to Spinner like,

```
android:background="@drawable/border.xml"
```

I hope it may help you... :)

Comment: that creates border for every dropdown item and I'm interested in border of "parent" holder of those items